# Attempts to check for element not existing with React Testing Library always failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component which in some circumstances should render nothing (it just returns `null`). It looks something like this:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ renderNothing }) => {
    if (renderNothing) {
        return null
    }
    return <div data-testid='my-component'>Stuff</div>
}
```

I would like to test that when in fact `renderNothing` is true, that the element with the data-testid of `my-component` does not exist. My current test looks something like this:

```js
  it.only('should not render MyComponent when renderNothing is true ', async () => {
    render(<MyComponent renderNothing={true}/>)
    const myComponent = screen.getByTestId('my-component')
    expect(myComponent).not.toBeInTheDocument()
  });
```

Unfortunately this test always fails with the following message:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="my-component"]

Is there a way to successfully do this check without triggering the error?

Comment: use `queryByTestId` https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs [Types of Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#types-of-queries):

> `getBy...`: Returns the matching node for a query, and **throws a descriptive error if no elements match** or if more than one match is found (use getAllBy instead if more than one element is expected).

> `queryBy...`: Returns the matching node for a query, and returns null if no elements match. This is useful for asserting an element that is not present. Throws an error if more than one match is found (use `queryAllBy` instead if this is OK).

You should use `queryByTestId()` method.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const MyComponent = ({ renderNothing }) => {
  if (renderNothing) {
    return null;
  }
  return <div data-testid="my-component">Stuff</div>;
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from './';

describe('68258524', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    render(<MyComponent renderNothing={true} />);
    const myComponent = screen.queryByTestId('my-component');
    expect(myComponent).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68258524/index.test.tsx (10.749 s)
  68258524
    ✓ should pass (23 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   83.33 |       50 |     100 |      80 |                   
 index.tsx |   83.33 |       50 |     100 |      80 | 7                 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.256 s
```